# Calculate the overall distance based on longitude and latitude

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question & Attempt**: Given that we have the start point of travel and end point $(longtitude_0, latitude_0)$, $(longtitude_1, latitude_1)$ coordinates. I used the **Haversine formula** to find distance between the two points. The problem is I got distance to be 2 meters although the the track is much more longer than that as the travel starts from one city and ends at another city and then travel back to original distention, so I see this might be the reason why I got only 2 meters.

**Problem**: can you please give hints how to find overall distance given that start $(longtitude_0, latitude_0)$ and end $(longtitude_1, latitude_1)$ are very close as I start from a specific location in a city and come back to the very close location in the same city? Should I calculate distance between each two consecutive points $(longtitude_{i}, latitude_{i})$ and end $(longtitude_{i+1}, latitude_{i+1})$ and then sum all of these together please?

Comment: The haversine formula just gives the straight-line distance between two points, where on a sphere "line" means along a great-arc.  Of course it says nothing about the actual path taken. For an arbitrary path, you can break it down in very small stretches where it nearly moves in a straight line, use the haversine formula to estimate the lengths of each of those stretches, then sum the lengths to estimate the length of the full path. For any reasonable path, the shorter the stretches you break it into, the closer this estimate will be to the actual length.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. Thank you. So how I did not is not true by taking each consecutive pairs of longitude and latitudes, calculate their haversine distance and sum all these up for all other pairs please?

Comment: As I said, you can *estimate* the length that way. Whether the estimate is good or bad depends on what path is taken between the consecutive points in your list. If at each point the path turns and heads straight towards the next point, then the sum of the lengths will be the exact length of the path. But if the path winds around between the points that you have data for, then the estimate will be poor. It depends on how many points you know vs how curvy your path is.